# Periodic task execution in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, scheduled-tasks

**How to reliably execute a function every few seconds in Sencha Touch?**
I am using following code to call function after every 7 seconds:

```js
var task = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function() {
    function();
    task.delay(7000);
}, this);
task.delay(0);
```

It works on iPhone and desktop (chrome) but i am having problem with Android, i.e on Android it is not working. I also tried by using *setInterval* method & *setTimeout*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with `setTimeout` ?

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 0):

From [this blog post](http://tb-it.blogspot.com/2011/12/sencha-touch-repeating-tasks.html), modified a bit.

> ... so here is a trivial set of extensions to the Ext.util.Functions class that provide the ability to create repeating tasks, and some simple management of them.

```js
Ext.apply(Ext.util, {  
  repeat: function(taskName, fn, millis, zeroDayExecution) {
    this.tasks = this.tasks || {};  
    if (zeroDayExecution)  
      fn();  
    return this.tasks[taskName] = window.setInterval(fn, millis);  
  },

  cancelRepeatingTask: function(taskName) {  
    if (this.tasks) {
      var id = this.tasks[taskName];  
      if (!Ext.isEmpty(id)) {  
        window.clearInterval(id);  
        delete this.tasks[taskName];  
      }
    }
  },

  cancelAllRepeatingTasks: function() {  
    if (this.tasks)  
    Object.keys(this.tasks).forEach(function(key) { 
                                    this.cancelRepeatingTask(key); }, 
                                    this);         
    }  
});
```

Example call:

```js
Ext.util.repeat('task1', function() { console.log('test'); }, 1000);
```